# Is Joseph the son of Jacob or Heli?

Tags: jesus, gospels, chronology, joseph, family

In Matthew 1:16 Joseph is said to be the son of Jacob.

> "Jacob begat Joseph the husband of Mary"

In Luke 3:23 Joseph is said to be the son of Heli.

> "Joseph, which was the son of Heli"

Which account do we believe to be more accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which account do we believe to be more accurate?

They are both accurate according to the early church historian [Eusebius](http://marshallgenealogy.org/bible/matthew-luke.htm).

[image]

As suggested by EvilSnack's comment:

> Matthew 1:16 Jacob [biologically] begat Joseph the husband of Mary

> Luke 3:23 Joseph the [legal] son of Heli

Comment: http://marshallgenealogy.org/bible/matthew-luke.htm

Comment: If you look at the text, one of the accounts (Matthew's) says that Jacob *begat* Joseph, whereas the other account says that Eli was the father of Joseph. As with most claims of contradictions in the Scriptures, they exist only because the claimant insists on specific interpretations of the verses in question, when reasonable non-contradictory interpretations exist.

Comment: Good point. Thanks :)